# "Function.prototype.toString called on incompatible object" on older versions of firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, babeljs

My website fails to load on older versions of Firefox.

The following is displayed in my console:

`TypeError: Function.prototype.toString called on incompatible object`.

I also see a warning that complains: `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly`, but this was a [known issue with FF](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/46) that didn't actually impact site responsiveness. So ignoring this warning for now.

The `Function.prototype.toString` error is my main focus, just because I want the site to actually show up for FF users. It seems like it's coming from a collection of babel-related node modules, including but not limited to: `babel-core/browser-polyfill.min.js`, `babel-core/browser.min.js`, `babel-polyfill/browser.js`, etc.

I depend on these libraries to transpile my ES6 react code, but haven't been able to find any fixes yet. Any insight into a workaround would be amazing.

*Screenshot of console*:
[image]

**UPDATE 1**

From what I could see in the console, the minified `browser-polyfill.min.js` complained about this line:

```
(Function.prototype,u,function(){return"function"==typeof this&&this[i]||c.call(this)})}
```

Specifically the ending, where it tries to attempt `c.call(this)`.

Upon doing some digging it seems that this is the corresponding line in an unminfied version:

```
(Function.prototype, TO_STRING, function toString(){
  return typeof this == 'function' && this[SRC] || $toString.call(this);
})
```

Still at a loss as to what exactly the issue is...

Comment: do you use lodash?

Comment: yes, but I've updated to the latest v4.12 and apparently that should [no longer be an issue](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr/issues/73)

Comment: In this thread they mention an issue with coerecting the Promise constructor in a worker. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2185 Its possible that babel polyfill has the same issue as lodash had in the past

Comment: Are you able to replace the minified versions of the polyfill with an unminified one so you can get a proper stack trace? There isn't a ton to go on at the moment.

Comment: good idea @loganfsmyth, just updated my question

Comment: Are you getting this exception upon loading the polyfills, or is there any transpiled code involved?

Comment: I'm transpiling React which is written in ES6. But nowhere in my codebase do I use `toString`

Comment: Run the unminified `browser-polyfill.js`, tell Firefox to pause JS on exceptions, and debug.